# Value of custom field in Custom Membership Provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, profile-provider

I have implemented Custom Membership Provider by inheriting .NETs Membership Provider. For my front end using CreateUserWizard Control, which is wired with mine Membership Provider. I have edited template of CreateUserWizard control, so now it looks like this:

```
 <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
                    MembershipProvider="CmsMembershipProvider" BackColor="#E3EAEB" 
                    BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
                    ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/Pages/FirstPage.aspx">
                    <ContinueButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C5BBAF" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
                    <CreateUserButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C5BBAF" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
                    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <WizardSteps>
                        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" class="style3">
                                            <strong>Sign Up for Your New Account</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" name="usna" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                                AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                                ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                                ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="DomainLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Domain">Domain:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Domain" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DomainRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Domain" ErrorMessage="Domain is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Domain is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="5" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
                                    <tr align="right">
                                        <td align="right" colspan="0">
                                            <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                                                BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                                CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" 
                                                Text="Create User" ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </CustomNavigationTemplate>
                        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                    </WizardSteps>
                    <FinishNavigationTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="FinishPreviousButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                            BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                            ForeColor="#1C5E55" Text="Previous" />
                        <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                            BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CommandName="MoveComplete" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" 
                            Text="Finish" />
                    </FinishNavigationTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderStyle="Solid" 
                        BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C5BBAF" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                        ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
                    <SideBarButtonStyle ForeColor="White" />
                    <SideBarStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Size="0.9em" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                    <StartNavigationTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="StartNextButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                            BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" Text="Next" />
                    </StartNavigationTemplate>
                    <StepNavigationTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                            BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                            ForeColor="#1C5E55" Text="Previous" />
                        <asp:Button ID="StepNextButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                            BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                            CommandName="MoveNext" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" Text="Next" />
                    </StepNavigationTemplate>
                    <StepStyle BorderWidth="0px" />
                </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

It have original fieds minus SecurityQuestion and Answer, but in addition I have field Domain wich is TextBox.

I have override method CreateUser, so it looks like this:

```
public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {

        ValidatePasswordEventArgs args = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs(username, password, true);
        OnValidatingPassword(args);

        AccountDB accountDB = new AccountDB();

        string usn = username;
        string eml = email;
        string passSalt = AccountDB.CreateSalt();
        string pass = AccountDB.CreatePasswordHash(password, passSalt);  
        DateTime crtDt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime lstMdfDt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime lstLgnDt = DateTime.Now;
        string lstLgnIp = (string)HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        byte isAct = 0;
        string cmnt = "komentar";

        AccountDetails accountDetails = new AccountDetails(usn, eml, pass, passSalt, crtDt, lstMdfDt, lstLgnDt, lstLgnIp, isAct, cmnt);

        if (args.Cancel)
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
            return null;
        }
        if(RequiresUniqueEmail && !accountDB.IsEmailUnique(email))
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
            return null;
        }
        if (!accountDB.IsUsernameUnique(username))
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
            return null;
        }
        else 
        {
            status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
            int idOfInsertedUser = accountDB.InsertAccount(accountDetails);

            int lanId = 1;
            int pySclId = 1;
            int appTypId = 1;
            int indSecId = 1;
            int thmId = 1;
            string appName = "ApplicationName";

           // ApplicationDetails applicationDetails = new ApplicationDetails(0,lanId, pySclId, idOfInsertedUser, appTypId, indSecId, thmId, appName);
         //   ApplicationDB applicationDB = new ApplicationDB();
           // int idOfApplication = applicationDB.InsertApplication(applicationDetails);


            //DomainDB domainDB = new DomainDB();
          // This is where i want to have value of textBox Domain in variable domainName
            //DomainDetails domainDetails = new DomainDetails(0, idOfApplication, domainName);
            //domainDB.InsertDomain(domainDetails); 
            return accountDB.GetAccount(idOfInsertedUser);
        }

    }
```

It inserts to database perfectly, but I cannot get the value of TextBox Domain from the form, because Create User does not sends that variable.
I found some examples who says, that i could create another step in CreateUserWizard and then Update database with new sets of values, but I do not want to do that in different step. Can it be done in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have extra information for a user other that what the default is you might want to consider creating a [Custom Membership User](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-membership-user/). You can then provide another override to `CreateUser` method to insert that information.

Comment: I was considering this... Another option is to add onCreatedUser event on CreateUserWizard control and handle value of additional field inside method that fires up. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: @stanislav - You could to that, but this way you'll have a central place that will handle your extra information and you will only have to call Membership to get that extra info if you need it in other places.